# Intel Nuc (NUC6i5SYB) - Power On After AC Power is Restored (is not reliable)

Tags: bios, power, intel-nuc

We have Ubuntu Server running on a [NUC6i5SYB](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/NUC6i5SYB_NUC6i3SYB_TechProdSpec.pdf) that's powered by a [UPS](https://www.apc.com/us/en/product/BX1500G/apc-powersaving-backups-xs-1500va/). In the BIOS, I have this power option saved:

```
After Power Failure: Power ON
```

In the manual, it says this option means: "System will automatically power-on after AC power is restored" :

[image]

When I test this manually, by unplugging the power adapter (and plugging it back in), the system does indeed automatically power on as desired.

However, on occasions when the power goes out long enough to completely discharge the UPS, this NUC does NOT power on after power is restored. Other devices, connected to this same UPS, do indeed power on once power is restored.

I believe I'm running the latest BIOS:

```
Intel v: SYSKLi35.86A.0073.2020.0909.1625 date: 09/09/2020
```

On multiple occasions now, I've had to drive onsite (late at night) to turn this NUC on manually. I'd appreciate any suggestions that might address this issue once and for all.

Comment: It sounds as though the UPS is part of the picture. Is there a data connection from UPS to server PC? Does the UPS return to normal power state once grid is restored?

Comment: The USP is an [APC XS-1500](https://www.apc.com/us/en/product/BX1500G/apc-powersaving-backups-xs-1500va/). I see that is does have a [data port](https://i.imgur.com/TGlmhYs.png) that I'm not currently using. Except for the [NUC6i5SYB](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/NUC6i5SYB_NUC6i3SYB_TechProdSpec.pdf), all other devices (plugged into this same UPS) do power on after the UPS's power is restored. @fred_dot_u